# Reading Dump file through Debug engine API

Tags: c++, com, windbg

I have written a small program using Debug engine API to read a dump file.
I am executing `!analyze -v` command through code.

I am able to get almost every detail that could be extracted with above command but not the Process Name and Image name and module name

I really don't know where I'm going wrong.

Things i tried:

1. copied the dll's ext,exts,Kdexts,kext to the same folder where my exe is 
   present.
2. also copied the symsrv.dll.
3. for symbol path i am using
   `symbols->SetSymbolPath("srv*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols")` where symbols is an IDebugSymbols pointer

But so far it didn't work.

The result i'm getting is :

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION (f4) A process or thread crucial to system
operation has unexpectedly exited or been terminated. Several
processes and threads are necessary for the operation of the system;
when they are terminated (for any reason), the system can no longer
function. Arguments: Arg1: 00000003, Process Arg2: 84d97860,
Terminating object Arg3: 84d979cc, Process image file name Arg4:
8285cec0, Explanatory message (ascii)

Debugging Details:
------------------

***** Debugger could not find nt in module list, module list might be incorrect,  error 0x80070057.

-----------------------------------------------                              
|         NT symbols are not available         | 
|         reduced functionality                | 
|                                              |
------------------------------------------------ 
unable to get nt!KiCurrentEtwBufferOffset 
unable to get nt!KiCurrentEtwBufferBase

PROCESS_OBJECT: 84d97860

IMAGE_NAME:  Unknown_Image

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

FAULTING_MODULE: 00000000 

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xF4

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

STACK_TEXT:   WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following
frames may be wrong. 950dbc9c 829223af 000000f4 00000003 84d97860
0x82722bfc 950dbcc0 828a0009 8285cec0 84d979cc 84d97ad0 0x829223af
950dbcf0 8289ff4c 84d97860 8447b030 00000001 0x828a0009 950dbd24
826818c6 000001e0 00000001 001cebb0 0x8289ff4c 950dbd34 77be70f4
badb0d00 001ceba8 00000000 0x826818c6 950dbd38 badb0d00 001ceba8
00000000 00000000 0x77be70f4 950dbd3c 001ceba8 00000000 00000000
00000000 0xbadb0d00 950dbd40 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x1ceba8


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

BUCKET_ID:  CORRUPT_MODULELIST

MODULE_NAME: Unknown_Module  *** Followup info cannot be found !!!
Please contact "Debugger Team"
```

Comment: How does it differ from the results you get in WinDbg directly?

Comment: In WinDbg im getting the value for BUCKET_ID, IMAGE_NAME, MODULE_NAME

Comment: but through my code i'm getting unknown module and Corrupt_moduleList.

Comment: In winDbg im setting same symbol path.....

Comment: After changing the symbol path, do you issue a `.reload`? I think it's necessary, if you didn't set the symbol path before loading the dump. Have you tried [Reload()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in code as well?

Comment: Im not changing any symbol path. Instead before opening dump file i'm setting the symbol path. Like we do in WinDbg we are pre-configuring symbol path , image path , source path.//  .reload is used if you are changing any path after opening dump file

Comment: The process was terminated because the machine blue-screened.  Stop error f4.  The reason for *that* mishap is not something you'll find out from this minidump.  You're done, tell the client to get his machine fixed.

Comment: Hi Hans i think you misunderstood something here . this minidump file was generated by me only for testing purpose to check whether through code can i read the dump file. as i said i am able to read most of the value for eg: stack trace, bug_check code.. The things which iám not able to read is the image name , module name.. untill n unless i got this im not done

Comment: I'm thinking that there is some problem with symbol path.. when i configured exe 
without any symbol path i got the same result.. 

may be i'm giving wrong symbol path or symbol is not getting downloaded from the 
url passed in symbol path

Answer (score 0):

set real directory names with ':' in SetSymbolPath()
"srv*http://..." is processed by another function not SetSymbolPath().